# Upgraded to .NET Framework 4.0 - Site down

Tags: asp.net, iis, configuration

Upgraded server Framework to 4.0. Using Godaddy hosting. The website is now showing this error

**500 - Internal server error.
There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed.**

On searching the internet found this:

[Error message when you visit a Web site that is hosted on IIS 7.0: "HTTP Error 500.0 – Internal Server Error"](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/942031)

The link above says:

Resolution 2
Make sure that the server that is running IIS 7.0 can access the configured root directory of the requested location.

I am not sure what to do.

Comment: Error 500 is a very generic error that could stem from lots of possible sources. Check the servers IIS and event logs, that should give you some more hints. Also you might want to post this (with more details) over at serverfault.

Comment: Not sure if this would help, but it's an issue I ran into when upgrading to .NET 4. The person who had managed the site before me had used IIS manager to configure settings and it added references to .NET 3.5 in the web.config. Removing all references/assemblies related to 3.5 and below fixed the issue.

Comment: @mjw06d: bingo.. I got some references to 3.5 dll.Now I cannot remove them as they are used by application. Do I need to port the application to vs2010 and recompile?

Comment: @Aseem Well if some of your applications are using 3.5, you may want to consider maintaining 2 app pools, one for your 4.0 apps and another for your 3.5. However in the 4.0 app, you'll need to remove all references to 3.5, add targetFramework="4.0" to compilation in web config

Comment: @Aseem Here is a good resource for you to browse through that may answer more questions you have. http://www.asp.net/learn/whitepapers/aspnet4/breaking-changes

Comment: @mjw06d: Your a life saver. Main site up and running.Need to convert all the subdomains now. Thanks!!

Comment: @Aseem Good to hear. Good luck with the rest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Moving from comment to answer so answer may be marked for future reference**

Not sure if this would help, but it's an issue I ran into when upgrading to .NET 4. The person who had managed the site before me had used IIS manager to configure settings and it added references to .NET 3.5 in the web.config. Removing all references/assemblies related to 3.5 and below fixed the issue.

Comment: I had the same problem and this solved it for me. While VS2010 fixed the web.config during upgrade to .net 4, there was another file (e.g. web_deployment.config) used in prod that was naturally not fixed by VS. Also, Browsing the web in IIS on the server gave me a better erro message than the "500"...

Answer (score 4):

Is your Application Pool running on .NET 4.0 or .NET 2.0?

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754523(WS.10).aspx

1. Open IIS Manager. For information about opening IIS Manager, see Open IIS Manager (IIS 7).
2. On the Connections pane, expand the server node and click Application Pools.
3. On the Application Pools page, select the application pool for which you want to specify a .NET Framework version, and then click Basic Settings in the Actions pane.
4. In the Edit Application Pool dialog box, in the .NET Framework version list, select the version that you want the application pool to use or select No Managed Code if the application uses only native code.
5. Click OK.

Comment: Well I am using shared hosting. These options are not visible. There is an option to recycle app pool. I have used it and its processing now.

Comment: Depending on your provider you might need to contact customer support and ask them to switch you to a .NET 4.0 Application Pool. I've had to do that before.

Comment: I think the problem is what @mjw06d says. I got some assemblies referring to .net 3.5. It is confirmed here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee941656.aspx

Answer (score 1):

This can also happen if you are using third party controls like Telerik or if something is wrong in the web.config file. Try to remove the httpHandlers/httpModules from web.config file and if this solves the problem, you can add them one by one to check which handler/module might be causing the problem.